# Processing custom NGINX log with logstash

Tags: nginx, elasticsearch, logstash, grok

I have nginx access log that log request body in the form of json string. eg.

```
"{\x0A\x22userId\x22 : \x22MyUserID\x22,\x0A\x22title\x22 : \x22\MyTitle\x0A}"
```

My objective is to store those 2 values (userId and title) into 2 separate fields  in Elastic Search.

My Logstash config:

```
filter {
  if [type] == "nginxlog" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG} %{QS:partner_id} %{NUMBER:req_time} %{NUMBER:res_time} %{GREEDYDATA:extra_fields}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]

    }

   mutate {
    gsub => [
      "extra_fields", x22 ,'"' ,
         "extra_fields",x0A ,'\n'

        ]
    }

    json{
        source => "extra_fields"
        target => "extra_json"

    }

   mutate {
    add_field => {

          "userId => "%{[extra_json][userId]}"
          "title"=> "%{[extra_json][title]}"
        }
 }



   }
}
```

But it's not properly extracted, the value in ES userId = userId, instead of MyUserID. Any clue where is the problem? Or any better idea to achieve the same?